# Weather information unavailable in calendar widget

Tags: gnome, weather

The calendar widget at the top of the screen used to work reasonably well, but it has been displaying "Weather information is currently unavailable" for at least the past week, possibly longer. If I click this text, it opens the Weather program, which does still work, so I assume it's something specific to the widget, not the underlying service providing weather data. A quick check of journalctl didn't turn up any error messages. Does anyone know how this widget obtains weather information or how to troubleshoot it?

Comment: Step 1: See if a similar issue has already been reported: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-weather/issues

Comment: My situation appears to be gnome-shell issue 1823: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/issues/1823 but there may be a different problem as well, being tracked as gnome-weather issue 84: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-weather/-/issues/84